# flutter_animate animating a widget when button is pressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

i am using flutter_animate package and i would like to animate my text when the button below is pressed. I found a way to do this but the text is getting animated when the widget is built. Maybe im doing something wrong when animating the text:

```
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationCtrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _animationCtrl = AnimationController(vsync: this);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: animateText(_animationCtrl),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
              _animationCtrl.forward();
              setState(() {});
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Animate animateText(AnimationController animationCtrl) {
    return Animate(
      child: Text("text")
          .animate(controller: animationCtrl)
          .moveX(end: 300, duration: 700.ms),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not initiate the controller inside the `build` method. Move it to `initState`:

```dart
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationCtrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationCtrl = AnimationController(vsync: this); // (1) Add this
  }

  // (3) Add the disposal too
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationCtrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // (2) Remove _animationCtrl instantiation line

    return MaterialApp(
```

After that, you should specify `autoPlay: false` inside `animate` so that it doesn't play automatically:

```dart
Text("text")
    .animate(controller: animationCtrl, autoPlay: false)
```

That should fix the issue.

---

Additionally, when you use `.animate` you don't need to wrap the widget with `Animate`. So just return the `Text` directly:

```dart
Animate animateText(AnimationController animationCtrl) {
  return Text("text")
      .animate(controller: animationCtrl, autoPlay: false)
      .moveX(end: 300, duration: 700.ms);
}
```

`setState` is not needed when forwarding an animation. You can remove it:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
  _animationCtrl.forward();
  // Remove the setState line
})
```